# How to combine 2 java methods into one efficiently

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a validate java class that receives 4 inputs from an object passed as 1 from the requester. The class needs to convert float inputs to string and evaluate each input to meet a certain format and then throw exceptions complete with error message and code when it fails.

What I have is in two methods and would like to know if there is a better way to combine these two classes into one validate method for the main class to call. I don't seem to be able to get around using the pattern/matcher concept to insure the inputs are formatted correctly. Any help you can give would be very much appreciated.

```
public class Validator {
private static final String MoneyPattern ="^\\d{1,7}(\\.\\d{1,2})$" ;
private static final String PercentagePattern = "^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2}$";
private static final String CalendarYearPattern = "^20[1-9][0-9]$";


private int errorcode = 0;
private String errormessage = null;



public Validator(MyInput input){

}

private boolean verifyInput(){ 

    String Percentage = ((Float) input.getPercentage().toString();
    String Income = ((Float) input.getIncome().toString();
    String PublicPlan = ((Float) input.getPublicPlan().toString();
    String Year = ((Float) input.getYear();

try {
           if (!doesMatch(Income, MoneyPattern)) {

           errormessage = errormessage + "income,";
       }
       if (!doesMatch(PublicPlan, MoneyPattern)) {

           errormessage = errormessage + "insurance plan,";
       }
       if (!doesMatch(Percentage, PercentagePattern)) {

           errormessage = errormessage + "Percentage Plan,";
       }
       if (!doesMatch(Year, CalendarYearPattern)) {

           errormessage = errormessage + "Year,";
       }

     } catch (Exception e){
        errorcode = 111;
        errormessage =  e.getMessage();
     }

}

private boolean doesMatch(String s, String pattern) throws Exception{

    try {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    if (!s.equals("")){
    if(m.find()){
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
    }else {
        return false;
    }
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse){
    errorcode = 111;
    errormessage = pse.getMessage();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `((Float) input.getPercentage()` is missing a parenthese.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to combine then? Modularising the code like that is much better than combining it.

Comment: please follow [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). it's really not that hard and makes it easier for us to understand your code

Comment: `errorcode = 111; errormessage =  e.getMessage();
` is a bit scary.  What does `111` mean? `getMessage()` is often null.

Answer (score 0):

This code is borked from the word "go".  You have a constructor into which you pass a `MyInput` reference, but there's no code in the ctor and no private data member to receive it.  It looks like you expect to use input in your `doesMatch(`) method, but it's a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen.

Your code doesn't follow the Sun Java coding standards; variable names should be lower case.

Why you wouldn't do that input validation in the ctor, when you actually receive the value, is beyond me.  Perhaps you really meant to pass it into that `verifyInput()` method.

I would worry about correctness and readability before concerning myself with efficiency.

I'd have methods like this:

```
public boolean isValidMoney(String money) { // put the regex here }
public boolean isValidYear(String year) { // the regex here }
```

I think I'd prefer a real Money class to a String.  There's no abstraction whatsoever.

Here's one bit of honesty:

```
private static final String CalendarYearPattern = "^20[1-9][0-9]$";
```

I guess you either don't think this code will still be running in the 22nd century or you won't be here to maintain it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Forgot to say i'm new to java so i will make those corrections you suggested. And yes i am trying to find a way to do as you say "....expect to use input in your doesMatch() method and that's why i was asking for ideas. Are you saying have:

Comment: You're very polite, but around here it works better if you vote up answers that help and accept the one that you think best answers your question.  You're new to SO as well, so please consider reading the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be with [DynamicBeans](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html).

```
package com.acme.validator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

public class Validator {

//A simple optimisation of the pattern
private static final Pattern MoneyPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,7}(\\.\\d{1,2})$");
private static final Pattern PercentagePattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2}$");
private static final Pattern CalendarYearPattern = Pattern.compile("^20[1-9][0-9]$");

public String Validator(MyInput input) {
    String errormessage = "";

    /*
     * Setting these up as Maps.
     * Ideally this would be a 'simple bean'
     * but that goes beyond the scope of the
     * original question 
     */
    Map<String,Pattern> patternMap = new HashMap<String,Pattern>();
    patternMap.put("percentage", PercentagePattern);
    patternMap.put("publicPlan", MoneyPattern);
    patternMap.put("income", MoneyPattern);
    patternMap.put("year", CalendarYearPattern);

    Map<String,String> errorMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    errorMap.put("percentage", "Percentage Plan,");
    errorMap.put("publicPlan", "insurance plan,");
    errorMap.put("income", "income,");
    errorMap.put("year", "Year,");

    for (String key : patternMap.keySet()) {
        try {
            String match = ((Float) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(input, key)).toString();
            Matcher m = patternMap.get(key).matcher(match);
            if ("".equals(match) || !m.find()) {
                errormessage = errormessage + errorMap.get(key);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errormessage = e.getMessage();  //since getMessage() could be null, you need to work out some way of handling this in the response
            //don't know the point of the error code so remove this altogether
            break; //Assume an exception trumps any validation failure
        }
    }
    return errormessage;
  }
}
```

I've made a few assumptions about the validation rules (for simplicity used 2 maps but you could also use a single map and a bean containing both the Pattern and the Message and even the 'error code' if that is important).

The key 'flaw' in your original setup and what would hamper the solution above, is that you are using 'year' as Float in the input bean.

```
(new Float(2012)).toString()
```

The above returns "2012.0". This will always fail your pattern. When you start messing about with the different types of objects potentially in the input bean, you may need to consider ensuring they are String at the time of creating the input bean and not, as is the case here, when they are retrieved.

Good Luck with the rest of your Java experience.

Comment: Thanks radimpe! This is the answer I was hoping for to give me ideas. I really appreciate it. Also the Float for the year was a typo thanks again.